# Get checkbox data and save it to database django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am creating a website where users can follow stocks and see articles based on what they follow. I am struggling to get the view that allows users to select which stocks they want to follow to work.

models.py

```
 from django.db import models
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    from django.dispatch import receiver
    from django.db.models.signals import post_save



    class Stock(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
        ticker = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.name

    class Profile(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        followed_stocks = models.ManyToManyField(Stock, blank=True)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.user.username

        @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
        def update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
            if created:
                Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
            instance.profile.save()

    class Article(models.Model):
        stock = models.ForeignKey(Stock, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default = 0 )
        title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
        url = models.URLField()
        description = models.TextField()

        def __str__(self):
            return self.title
```

forms.py:

```
class StockFollowForm(forms.Form):
    stocks = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(required =False,
                                           widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
                                           queryset=Stock.objects.all())
```

template:

```
{%  block body %}
    <div class = "container">
        <h2 class = "text-center">Register</h2>

        <form method = 'post'>
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form }}
            <div class = "text-center">
                <br/>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type = 'submit'>Follow</button>
            </div>

        </form>

    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

views.py:

```
 def follow_coins(request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = StockFollowForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                request.user.profile.followed_stocks = form.cleaned_data.get('stocks_selected')
                request.user.save()
                return redirect('index')
        else:
            form = StockFollowForm()
            return render(request, 'core/test.html',{'form': form})
```

This succesfully displays a form of all `Stock`s next to checkboxes, but how do I actually capture the data from the checkbox and save it to my database in the `test` view?

Comment: did you get to solve your problem? Was my answer below useful to you?

Answer (score 1):

You are saving the user in your view, but you probably need to save the profile as well since the field `followed_stocks` is in the profile.

```
request.user.save()
request.user.profile.save()   # add this line
```

Let me know if that helps.